# How to add a custom field to Django user module?

Tags: python, django

[This is the image of the default Django User fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8iZ9.png)

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Visitor(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  phone = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from accounts.models import Visitor

class VisitorInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Visitor
  can_delete = False
  verbose_name_plural = "visitor"

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (VisitorInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This image has the default Django user fields such as username, email address, first name and last name. I want to add a custom field such as a phone number to the existing fields. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: See [Extending the existing user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and [Substituting a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Please include the code and not a link to an image of the code.